# Retrieving a single fetch value from a function using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo, session-variables

```
    //This is my function in retrieving the id of the user base from its email and pass. this is for functions.php 
       function getID($email,$pass)
        {
                $pdo = new PDO(connection here);
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id user where email = :email and pass = :pass LIMIT 1');
            $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email, ':pass'=>md5($pass)));
            $result = $stmt->fetch();
            return $result['id'];//Is this the right way of returning a value from a fetch value?
        }
//this is for user.php. 
include 'function.php';
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = getID($_POST['email'],$_POST['pass']);
```

Is this the right way of retrieving it? but i do not get any values from it. Need help thanks!

Comment: Md5 has been broken. Please use SHA256 or better

Comment: so md5 is not advisable to use it anymore?

Comment: Found this article http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/md5-password-scrambler-no-longer-safe/12317. It seems it is broken - the passwords can be figured out from the md5 string. Sounds like if you add a proper "salt", it isn't as bad and if you only have a few users most hackers wont bother anyways, but yea, switch to something more secure.

Comment: sorry sir im just a newbie ^^ just been a week learning php., what do you mean by salt? hhehe how to make this more secure? any suggestions will be a big help! ^^

Comment: Wow can't believe no one responded - SELECT users.id, users.user FROM users WHERE users.email = :email AND users.pass = SHA2(CONCAT(users.salt, :pass), 256)

Comment: Apply the escaped password to your execute, add a salt column to the users table, on user creation generate a random salt and combine it with SHA2. $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, salt, pass) VALUES(:email, :salt, SHA2(CONCAT(:salt, :pass), 256))"); $salt = md5(rand()); $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':salt' => $salt, ':pass' => $pass) ); salt is just some extra padding that adds some entropy to otherwise identical passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is missing a `FROM`.

`SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = :email AND pass = :pass LIMIT 1`

Comment: Haha no need to be sorry, we've all been there